# Electron-Angular9 App showing blank white screen in Windows 7 , but working fine on Windows 8

Tags: windows-7, electron, electron-builder, angular9

My Electron App built for Windows with electron-builder is working fine on windows 8 , but showing white blank screen when the setup file installed on Windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix the issue After installing .NET 4.8 developer pack

Comment: You mean Installing .net 4.8 in node modules or where electron desktop app is installed?

Comment: In desktop pc , not in nodemodules(electron exe need not rebuilt)